# JSON string (encoded from large array) got truncated when output to HTTP client

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I met an issue that the JSON string output to HTTP client was truncated near to close tag.

An example,

a. expect to see - ... ... "last_update":"2014-06-10 20:46:38","garden_id":"1"}],"message":null}

b. actually it is - ... ..."last_update":"2014-06-10 20:46:38","garden_id":"1"}],"message":nul

The last two characaters were truncated for some reason!!!

I tried both Postman on Chrome and curl on a console, all the same output. So looks not a browser specific issue. The JSON string in my application comes from a PHP json_encode on an associative array. The PHP code is using CodeIgniter framework running on Apache. I tried to write the json string into a file before http output, the file content is 100% correct. So it is not a json encoding issue in PHP.

The PHP is pretty straightforward. I have build below array (namely $finaldata) from database query

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "file_id": "1",
            "title": "xxx",
            "create_date": "2014-05-18 21:30:19",
            "auditor": "1",
            "status": "1",
            "last_updater": null,
            "last_update": "2014-06-10 20:43:14",
            "garden_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "file_id": "2",
            "title": "yyy",
            "create_date": "2014-05-18 21:30:19",
            "auditor": "1",
            "status": "1",
            "last_updater": null,
            "last_update": "2014-06-10 20:43:14",
            "garden_id": "1"
        }
    ],
    "message": null
}
```

the "data" has a sub array and it could be a long array depends on database records. Then the variable $finaldata is passed to a output function that has below general logic:

```
header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format]);
$output = $this->format->factory($finaldata)->{'to_'.$this->response->format}();
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
```

The output function is built by a RESTful library from https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver. In this context, it equals to

```
header('Content-Type: Application/json');
$output = json_encode($finaldata);
```

But I found an interesting thing that the issue only happened if the string length exceeds 8K. And when I append a random string like "ZZZ" to the JSON string before HTTP response, the issue was gone. I don't know the reason behind. It is not a correct hack because I could not prove 8K is a real threshold though.

Has anyone met such issue before? Any suggestion or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you send the data in `UTF-8` charset so try to change this lines

```
header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format]);
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
```

into this one

```
header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format] . '; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($output));
```

If this doesn't work just don't send the `Content-Length` header at all. This header is "only useful" if you send a file to the browser (as a download).

Comment: just tried, doesn't work. My hack now is,

    if(strlen($output)>8000){
       $output = $output."ZZZ";
    }

Comment: Try to delete the `Content-Length` header statement and remove your workaround and have a look if the string still gets truncated.

Comment: wow, it seems work. It tells me the strlen() function is returning an incorrect size, right?

Comment: Is it possible due to my mbstring extension is not configured well? It is now configured in php.ini like this - [mbstring]
mbstring.language = all
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.http_input = auto
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
mbstring.detect_order = UTF-8
mbstring.substitute_character = none;
mbstring.func_overload = 0
mbstring.strict_encoding = Off

Comment: @navykoo Yep there seems to be a problem with `strlen()` and `mb_strlen()`. Can say if your mbstring now is configured right. Does it work with this settings you posted in the comment above? But if it works just don't send the `Content-Length` header at all.

Comment: Try also to add an `ob_clean()` before your output.
In my case, Yii Framework (1.1.16) add some spaces in front of it, changing the document's output length.

Answer (score 0):

In my issue, I enable gzip in nginx,and append `application/json` to the field of gzip_types. Then, I set a header when make a request with Guzzle. It looks like

```
    if (! isset($parameters['headers'])) {
        $parameters['headers']['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip';
    }
```