# PHP variable being truncated after POST

Tags: php, json, apache, post, content-length

I have the following PHP code which is being executed during a `POST` request:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
error_log($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']);
error_log(strlen($json));
```

On my local MAMP environment (PHP 5.6.2) I get this awesome response:

```
[08-Apr-2015 05:15:24 Europe/Berlin] 876406
[08-Apr-2015 05:15:24 Europe/Berlin] 876406
```

On my server environment (PHP 5.5.9) I get this **extremely aggrevating** response:

```
[Tue Apr 07 23:16:24.506986 2015] 876406
[Tue Apr 07 23:16:24.507036 2015] 162176
```

When I `error_log` the `$json` variable it is indeed truncated. I've opened both `php.ini` files side-by-side and there's nothing different. Is there something Apache might be doing to long requests that I don't know about? This is impeding my ability to parse my `$json` object and submit to my database (**this is a big problem for me**)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON string (encoded from large array) got truncated when output to HTTP client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307397/json-string-encoded-from-large-array-got-truncated-when-output-to-http-client)